# How do I run through a 2D array that contains 3 values and run a check for the values?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, objective-c++

Ok so i really think I'm over thinking this, but I've been programming for 48 hours straight and my mind is gone. Background info: using Visual Studio 2010, creating a console application using C++. I was having trouble with some logic, and got stuck on the following:

I have a 2 dimensional 8 x 8 array, matrix[8][8].  This array contains either 0's, 1's, and 2's.  Now as the program executes the array replaces either the 1's or 2's with 0's.  So as it is running, I want to have a check to see if the array has removed either all of the 1's or 2's.  So if there are only 0's and 1's I want to cout a message saying something like "your array no longer contains 2's" and vice versa if there are only 0's and 2's.

Here is some code i was thinking of using:

```
for(row = 0; row < 8; row++)
{
    for (col = 0; col < 8; col++)
    {
        if(matrix[row][col] != 1){
            cout<<"message"<<endl; }

        else if(matrix[row][col] != 2){
            cout<<"message"<<endl; }
    }
}
```

Now my problem with this is that if the array contains [0, 1, 2, 0] it would run through and check the first element, and it wouldnt contain a 1 or a 2. Some ideas as to what i could do please?

Comment: A bunch of hints: Wrap your matrix in a class, use iterators for that class, matrix[col * row] is more efficient. If you did this solving your problem is a simple `fold` or `accumulate` (in C++ terms) away.

This also keeps your mind from "being gone".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot decide that inside the loop. You only know the result after going through the whole matrix:

```
bool hasOnes = false;
bool hasTwos = false;
for(row = 0; row < 8; row++)
{
    for (col = 0; col < 8; col++)
    {
        if(matrix[row][col] == 1) {
          hasOnes = true;
        } else if(matrix[row][col] == 2){
          hasTwos = true;
        }
}

if (hasOnes && !hasTwos)
  cout << "You have removed twos" << endl;
if (hasTwos && !hasOnes)
  cout << "You have removed ones" << endl;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks everyone, the fast responses were perfect.  Great community here at Stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you iterate over the matrix and count all elements like this:

```
int counts[3];
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    counts[i] = 0;
}
for(row = 0; row < 8; row++)
{
    for (col = 0; col < 8; col++)
    {
        counts[matrix[row][col]]++;
    }
}
```

Once you have this, you can simply check for `counts[1]` to see the number of ones in the matrix. Also, if you are iteratively replacing the values, you can avoid re-checking the full matrix after each iteration. You can change the counts as you change the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you will *only* have 0-2 in each array element:
    int vals = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++)
        for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++)
        {
            vals |= matrix[row][col];
            if (vals == 3)
                 break;
        }
    if (vals & 1) cout << "Matrix contains 1's" << endl;
    if (vals & 2) cout << "Matrix contains 2's" << endl;

Answer (score 0):

```
int count[3] = {0,0,0};
for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) count[*(matrix + i)]++;

if (count[0] + count[1] == 64) cout<<"No 2s exist"<<endl;
if (count[0] + count[2] == 64) cout<<"No 1s exist"<<endl;
```

**Edit**
This may be slightly faster

```
int count[3] = {0,0,0};
for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) 
     if (!count[1] && !count[2]) count[*(matrix + i)]++;
     else break;

if (count[0] + count[1] == 64) cout<<"No 2s exist"<<endl;
if (count[0] + count[2] == 64) cout<<"No 1s exist"<<endl;
```

Comment: This also works, but a boolean statement seems easier to me. Thank you!

Comment: @tehman if you have the count variable, it would be easier to wrap this loop into the code where you update the matrix. You could do something like count[old_value[--; count[new_value]++; when you are updating the matrix and just use the if condition at the bottom. Reduces an overhead of a loop.